# Bulk inserting in database unique codes

Tags: python, django, database

I need create a lot of unique codes and insert it in database.

Of course I can write something like this:

```
codes = set()
while len(codes) < codes_size:
    c = generate_code()
    if len(Codes.objects.filter(code=c)) == 0:
        codes.add(Codes(c))
Codes.objects.bulk_create(codes)
```

But when database already contain a lot of codes it works very slow.

If insert code after each generation  - it's very slow too.

Now best idea - not verify code until `bulk_create`. And if `bulk_create` raise exception then regenerate all codes again. Exceptions very rare, but when database will be more bigger then and exceptions will be more often.

`bulk_create` not say which code raise exception.

Comment: Using `not Code.objects.filter(code=c).exists()` instead of `len(Codes.objects.filter(code=c)) == 0` will increase the efficiency of your code even if it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that `bulk_create()` performs it's operation within a *transaction* which is not committed if an error occurs. This means that either *all* inserts succeeded, or *none* succeeded.

For example, if a code is generated that is a duplicate of one that is already in the table, or a duplicate of another within the batch, an `IntegrityError` exception would be raised and *none* of the codes would have been inserted into the database.

In terms of exceptions, you'll likely get a subclass of `django.db.utils.DatabaseError`, e.g. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError`. Because you don't know which database error will be raised you should catch `DatabaseError`.

I don't think that there is any way to know from the exception which of the codes caused the problem.

One way to handle this is to generate all of the codes up front and then, within a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/), test whether they already exist in the table in one go using `filter()` and insert them if there are no duplicates:

```
from django.db import transaction

codes = set()
while len(codes) < codes_size:
    codes.add(generate_code())

with transaction.atomic():
    # check for any duplicate codes in table...
    dups = Codes.objects.filter(code__in=codes)
    if len(dups):
        print 'Duplicate code(s) generated: {}'.format(dup.code for dup in dups)
        # remove dups from codes, and generate additional codes to make up the shortfall.
        # Note that this might also result in duplicates....
    else:
        Codes.objects.bulk_create(Codes(code) for code in codes)
```

You still need to handle database exceptions that are not due to duplicate values. For simplicity I've left that out.

Comment: `dups = Codes.objects.filter(code__in=codes)` is discovery for me. Thank you.